# What is an appropriate name of a field replacing "description" which is reserved in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, naming

I wrote a thrift IDL like the following:

```
struct Product {
    1: string name,
    2: string description
}
```

After publishing this IDL, I have noticed that 'description' is a kind of 'reserved' in iOS because `NSObject` class has ['description' class method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description) and this `IDL` is supposed to be used in iOS.

I've been thought about this topic and got some candidates:

- detail
- details
- detailedText
- descriptionText

But I couldn't figure out which one is best (in terms of naturalness and conciseness) since I'm not a native English speaker.

I understand naming things depends on its domain area, 
but I'm sure that 'description' of something is pretty common concept and
many iOS developers are puzzled by `NSObject` thing.

Comment: Sometimes I've just added "the" in front -- eg, "theDescription".  But it really doesn't matter much -- just pick a scheme and try to be reasonably consistent with it,

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `description` is a named message on `NSObject`.

You should be able to use it in a structure, but I can see where it might cause a problem when you use `.` (auto completion can be good and bad).

I think "details" is a good choice.  If you use something with "Text" in the name, it may look odd unless you do it for others.

You can use a convention like `strName`, `strDescription`, etc., to identify the type of the variable and you will not have an issue either.

If you want to put "Text" in the variable name, you should be consistent (`nameText`, `descriptionText`), etc.

You could also use a variable name with a capital first letter:  "Name", "Description", etc.
However, this is **not** the Apple convention for naming variables.

Comment: The ObjC convention for variable names is to always start with lower-case letters.

Comment: That is a fair and valid point.  I will update my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

When we are talking about naming conventions, you should know that there is no right and no wrong here. Apple posted [a document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) which explains why they use such a naming convention.

But if you are looking for an alternative to your `struct`, maybe you should go deeper and reach for a native C naming convention (`struct` is from C, not Objective-C). And then you could use Hungarian Notation for example, but I don't recommended this at all.

Here is what I do - I'm always naming my variables from the class. This is what Apple does in some cases (look at method `capitalizedString` - this method could be named just `capitalized`, right? Because you can only use it for a string). So in your case the name will be 'descriptionProduct' or 'descriptionOfTheProduct' or even 'descProduct'. The case is that you will never forget what you have in mind because you have at least "desc" to code sense catch the full name for you.

If you're connecting to some kind of REST service you should always keep the beginnings of the names the same, because you'll simply forget what matches what. So if you're receiving the "description" form your service use "desc..." (even just for code sense).

But you cannot be right or wrong answering this kind of question.

Comment: I do it exactly the other way around ;) I start with let's say `article` and then I can see what possibilities I have like `articleNumber`, `articleDescription` or `articlePrice`. Anyways, +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is in a `struct`, it doesn't conflict with the method named `description` at all. You can safely use just `description` here.

However, you can perhaps be more, um, descriptive, in your name as well. *What* is the "description" describing? The struct itself, or the product that it represents? If the latter, `productDescription` would be an excellent choice.